How to get the corners of a rectangle from the SmallestRectangle2 function
I'm trying to determine the four corners of a rectangle when I only have the midpoint, half-length, and half-width (data obtained when I apply the SmallestRectangle2 function).
I attempted to use the following equations:
Top Right:
x = cx + halfWidth * cos(Phi) - halfLength * sin(Phi)
y = cy + halfWidth * sin(Phi) + halfLength * cos(Phi)
Top Left:
x = cx - halfWidth * cos(Phi) - halfLength * sin(Phi)
y = cy - halfWidth * sin(Phi) + halfLength * cos(Phi)
Bottom Right:
x = cx + halfWidth * cos(Phi) + halfLength * sin(Phi)
y = cy + halfWidth * sin(Phi) - halfLength * cos(Phi)
Bottom Left:
x = cx - halfWidth * cos(Phi) + halfLength * sin(Phi)
y = cy - halfWidth * sin(Phi) - halfLength * cos(Phi)
However, the results seem to be rotated by 90 degrees. So, I tried adding 90 degrees (in radians) to Phi, and I'm getting closer, but there's still a margin of error.
